# Solutions For System Of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> For which values of $a$ the system has one/none/infinite solutions, write the general solution
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_1+(a-1)x_2-x_3=4\\
> ax_1+(a-1)x_2-x_3=a+3\\
> x_1+(a-1)x_2+(a-3)x_3=7
> \end{cases}
> $$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & a-1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & -(a-1)^2 & a-1 & -3a+3 \\ 
0 & 0& a-2 & 3 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$$

So for $a=2$ there is no solution, $a\neq2,1$ there is one solution and for $a=1$ there is infinite solutions in this case we have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0& 0 & 0 \\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$$

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_1-x_3=4\rightarrow x_1=1\\
> -x_3=3\rightarrow x_3=-3\\
> \end{cases}
> $$

So the general solution is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
t \\
-3\\
\end{pmatrix}=t\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
1 \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0\\
-3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: @Moo you must assume $a\neq 0$ right?

Comment: @Moo Yes, but for the process of row reduction, you need to assume that $a\neq 0$ else for example you can divide a row with $0$

Comment: @Moo yes it will just delete the (2,1) entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we have $\det(A)=(a - 1)^2(a - 2)$ for the system $(A,b)$, so that there is a unique solution for $a\neq 1,2$. For $a=2$, as you said, we obtain $0=3$, which is correct for fields of characteristic $3$, but a contradiction otherwise. For $a=1$ we have a $1$-dimensional kernel $(0,1,0)^T$, and the general solution follows from this. Assuming that the field is infinite, we obtain infinitely many solutions.